# Accounts with ether cannot execute transaction on private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, poa

According to Metamask my accounts have ether, one account can submit transactions and have them be executed by the network, the other two have their transactions left as `Submitted transaction`.

Note, the account that works has a private key in the keystore in the chain's datadir.  The other two accounts were added to metamask and had ether sent to them with `web3.eth.sendTransaction()`.

I am not sure why their transactions are not being executed by the PoA network, they are also not sealers in the network, could this be why?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you configured your PoA network, it could be you disallowed transaction sending for everyone and instead set up the permission-only setting: https://wiki.parity.io/Permissioning